# How to setup switch for SSH connection between Virtualbox Ubuntu and Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox

I have 3 computers: 1 uses Ubuntu 20.04, and the other 2 is using Windows 10 which has Ubuntu using Virtualbox.

Normally, if 3 computers connected to the same WiFi, 3 computers can connect to each other using SSH. In the Virtualbox setting, I just need to change the Network adapter 2 to `Bridged Adapter` and I will have the IPv4 address for connecting SSH.

Now, I want to connect it using a single switch, how can set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the VirtualBox network settings, I have to change the Network Adapter Name to the LAN port that connects to the switch. In my case, my laptop uses the USB to Ethernet adapter so I choose `ASIX AX8877C USE2.0 to Fast Ethernet Adapter`.

[image]

Some laptop has built-in LAN port so you can check the name of it by open Network and Sharing Center and open the Ethernet 4 Properties.

[image]

That is done for Windows. Then on the Ubuntu laptop, in the Wired settings, I have to change the IPv4 Method from `Automatic (DHCP)` to `Shared to other computers`.

So the Ubuntu laptop will be the DHCP server that will generate the IP address for every laptop connect to it via the switch.

[image]